# Program not working even though no error

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            int a = 127;
            int v = Roll(a);
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Roll for (0) is (1), ", a, v));
        }
        int Roll (int x)
        {
            return (x <= 2) ? x : x + Roll(x / 2);
        }
    }
```

I have tried so many things with it but this is the best I could get and still its not working

Comment: You cannot have a method inside a method. Move  `Roll` outside of `button1_click`. Also remove additional `{}` inside `button1_Click` method

Comment: @Fcin actually you can, it's a new c# 7 feature

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the first line of your Click handler and run your app (F5). Does the breakpoint get hit? What happens when you step through this method?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Yes, but you have to target .net 4.7

Comment: Define "not working"

Comment: Yes, what is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: most of the issues can be easily fixed by reading the error message and/or the documentation for that function/feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is all wrong. See notes in comments below.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a = 127;
    int v = Roll(a);

    // Use curly braces, not parens for String.Format
    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Roll for {0} is {1}, ", a, v));

    // If you're using C# 6+, you could also use string interpolation
    MessageBox.Show($"Roll for {a} is {v}");
}

// Roll should be it's own method, outside of your click handler
private int Roll (int x)
{
    return (x <= 2) ? x : x + Roll(x / 2);
}

// Again, if you're using C# 6+, you could simplify your Roll method
// using expression bodied members
private int Roll (int x) => (x <= 2) ? x : x + Roll(x / 2);
```

**Additional Info**

- [String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings)
- [Expression Bodied Members](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2414582)

Comment: Thank you very much, @james-hill.I was stuck on this for a very long time.Very new to C# and can't get somethings right.You don't know how much this means.Thanks a lot, dear sir

Comment: @hackerred If that answer helped you, make sure to upvote and accept it.